# mysql: transaction? insert and update

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I need to do 2 query.

Basically it's a

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table ($value1,$value2)");
```

and

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table2 SET field1 = '$value1', field2 = '$value2'");
```

I think I can simply do a

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT ...") !== false) {
   mysql_query("UPDATE ...");
}
```

In this case should I use a transaction? And how should I use it?
Or can i leave that simple if?

Thanks

Comment: Is it okay to keep the insert if the update fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will generally use transactions if you want some "all or nothing" behavior.

Basically, with transactions, you can :

- Start a transaction
- Do the first query
- If it succeeds, do the second query

  - If it succeed, commit the transaction
  - Else, rollback the transaction -- cancelling both queries that correspond to that transaction.

If working with [`mysql_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) function, you'll have to :

- Start the transaction, with a `START TRANSACTION` query
- Do your queries
- Depending on the result of those queries, either do a `COMMIT` or a `ROLLBACK` query.

To detect whether a query succeeded or not, you can indeed check the return value of [`mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) : it will return `false` in case of an error.

Note : MySQL is the old extension -- and doesn't have functions to deal with transactions ; which means you have to deal with them as regular queries.

Working with [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli), you could use :

- [`mysqli::autocommit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php) to disable autocommit
- and [`mysqli::commit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) or [`mysqli::rollback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php)

Comment: this doesn't reply if i should use a transaction in this case or not xD

Comment: Do you want an *"all or nothing"* behavior or not ? *(we cannot guess that for you ;-) )* If you do, use a transaction ; if you don't... well, no need for a transaction.

Comment: Yes I want all or not (but I think it's clear from my IF in my question) xD.... so basically before all my query i do a query with START TRANSACTION, at the end of my query i do a commit? How can i keep track if some query did fail and i need to do a rollback?

Comment: ok you said I should check the return value of mysql_query.. in case it returns FALSE i do a rollback right?... but that's pretty awful if i have a lot of query

Comment: That's why we tend to use exceptions (and PDO, instead of mysql_* -- it can throw exceptions in case of an error) ; this way, only one roolback, in the catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

For insert and updates MySQL has a good, alternative solution - "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE". It does what you want safely in a single query:

```
INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

(also the key must be set as unique in this scenario)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html